# ParseFacebookUtils Error on ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to add in Facebook login with my app, I however get this exception and can't figure it out. The `ParseFacebookUtilsv4.jar` is in the libs folder. If more information is needed please let me know what is needed. I get the error on         `ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this)`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/android/Facebook;
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.<init>(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:81)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:134)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:104)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sweatmobile.sweat.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:38)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5932)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:198)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1737)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.android.Facebook" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sweatmobile.sweat-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.<init>(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:81) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:134) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:104) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sweatmobile.sweat.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:38) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1021) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5932) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:198) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1737) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.android.Facebook
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:          ... 16 more
    11-05 01:20:35.422 22399-22399/com.sweatmobile.sweat E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: your facebook library are not find when you initialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same error before. But now I fixed the error.

Please don't use `ParseFacebookUtilsv4.jar` file.

You can download the source of SDK here : 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android

Load the source of SDK not jar file and try again.

Thanks.